# Can't auto create more then 1 INT to database

Tags: mysql

The INT's I am referring to are the ones that have been separated by a space at the bottom of this table creation code. If I do not include the extra INT's then the table does get made to the database. Can you spot what I am doing wrong or is it just that I cant create more then one INT at a time with a Table creation file?

Thanks

```
$tbl_users = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
                     id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                     username VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                     email VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                     password VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                     gender ENUM ('m','f') NOT NULL,
                     website VARCHAR (255) NULL,
                     country VARCHAR (255) NULL,
                     userlevel ENUM('a','b','c','d') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'a',
                     avatar VARCHAR (255) NULL,
                     banner VARCHAR (255) NULL,
                     ip VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
                     signup DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     lastlogin DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     notecheck DATETIME NOT NULL,
                     activated ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     xbox ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     psn ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     steam ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     provname VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                     provider ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     teamname VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                     team ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     castname VARCHAR (16) NOT NULL,
                     followers TEXT NULL,
                     following_users TEXT NULL,
                     following_providers TEXT NULL,
                     following_teams TEXT NULL,
                     favorite_teams TEXT NULL,
                     favorite_providers TEXT NULL,
                     likers TEXT NULL,

                     followers_total INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '0',
                     following_total INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '0',
                     likes INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '0',
                     views INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT DEFAULT '0',

                     caster ENUM('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
                     PRIMARY KEY (id),
                     UNIQUE KEY username (username,email)

                 )";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $tbl_users);    
    if ($query === TRUE) {
        echo "<h3>user table created OK :) </h3>";
    } else {
        echo "<h3>user table NOT created :( </h3>";
    }
```

OK so the problem is that this table will not be made unless I take out the 4 INT i have added. I have added the gaps between the INT's and code so you can see it easier. These spaces are not normally here. I have tried making them without the defaults at the end as well.

I just do not know the answer other then that I can't create more then 1 INT automatically but surely this is the reason why is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem isn't that you have more than one `INT`, but that you have more than one `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You can only have one `AUTO_INCREMENT` column per table.

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> **There can be only one AUTO_INCREMENT column per table**, **it must be indexed**, and **it cannot have a DEFAULT value**. An AUTO_INCREMENT column works properly only if it contains only positive values. Inserting a negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number. This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers “wrap” over from positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.

Only the first one (`id INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT`) should be an `AUTO_INCREMENT`; for the rest of them, it doesn't make sense. When you add a new user, you want `followers_total`, `following_total`, `likes`, and `views` to be `0`, not a number larger than whatever the last user got. Just take out `AUTO_INCREMENT` for those columns and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible.There can be only one `auto-increment` column and it must be defined as a key in MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't support multiple auto increment fields.  why do you need 5, you can just use the ID.